# Remove TraceParent header from HttpClient requests

Tags: c#, http-headers

When I send any requests with `HttpClient`, it automatically attaches the header [`TraceParent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.net.http.headers.headernames.traceparent) to the request headers. I tried clearing all the default request headers, but that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header `traceparent` or `Request-Id` specified by DiagnosticsHandler: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/release/5.0/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/DiagnosticsHandler.cs#L286

How to disable this behavior is described here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21012#issuecomment-616570453

> ASP.NET Core creates an Activity that represents the request by default. This is what tells HttpClient to send an outgoing request id header. You can disable it in a couple of ways:
>
> - By setting the current activity to null before making the request (Activity.Current = null)
> - By setting the environment variable DOTNET_SYSTEM_NET_HTTP_ENABLEACTIVITYPROPAGATION to "false" or "0".
> - By the AppContext switch System.Net.Http.EnableActivityPropagation to false